# Program not exiting properly

Tags: c#, console-application

I am working on a program that is supposed to run for 3 days checking for pending messages and I want it to skip some of the processing that it does if there are pending messages in the database but I want it to continue to the next day and if there are pending messages on the last day I want the program to exit.  The problem is that when I run it in debug mode in VS it starts over from the beginning including the Build process.  This is the code that I am using to check for the last day of the run:

```cs
intDateCompare = DateTime.Compare(dtDate2, dtDate3);
if (intDateCompare == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Finished, press <Enter> to quit");
    strFinished = Console.ReadLine();
    Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

It does the compare properly and runs the Exit command like expected when I put a breakpoint there but then it starts the Build process again.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Consider using release and not debug , give background worker service a read

Comment: Maybe use `Exit(0)` instead. `Exit(1)` means that the program exited with an error.

Comment: why do you need to call Exit() forcibly? If your main entry-point function completes, your program will normally terminate.

Comment: If you are in a loop, maybe you should exit the method with `return;` or `return 0;`

Comment: Yes, just return, there is no need to exit the program. Allow it to just exit gracefully instead of trying to force it.

Comment: The real question is: why do you run a program from VS? And you leave it for 3 days like that with VS running under the hood? Weird. Why can't you just build the program and run it directly from console? And not worry about VS rebuilding or not your app.

Comment: @Donald it would be helpful if you edited your question to ask a specific question. We can try to infer, but I'm not sure it's clear what you are asking. Are you unsure as to why the application is exiting in a particular fashion (with any particular message from Windows), or are you unsure of why you think the application is building when running in a debugger in Visual Studio?

Comment: Changing to Exit(0) worked thanks.